# datetime string differs on several machines

Tags: c#, sql

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem:

```
 Datetime? _startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["STARTDATE"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

On my machine, time is shown as 16-10-2015. The application runs without problems.

But on a machine with time shown as 10/16/2015 the application returns an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Thanks for your time

Comment: did you try `DateTime.ParseExact(reader["STARTDATE"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", null)`

Comment: yes, that doesnt work: "No overload for method Tostring...."

Comment: @user3114347 Wait, what exactly is `reader["STARTDATE"]`? Is this not a DateTime already? If so, you can simply use it directly (with a cast, like `(DateTime)reader["STARTDATE"]`) and you don't have to tostring it first and then parseexact it.

Comment: yes its a datetime column from a table. the format is like : Date = {16-10-2015 0:00:00}

Answer (score 4):

You stated in comments that `reader["STARTDATE"]` is from a datetime column in your database, in which case you shouldnt be "parsing" it at all, it is already a datetime

```
 Datetime? _startdate = (DateTime?)reader["STARTDATE"];
```

What you see in the database is not a "format" that it is in - its just the format your database chooses to *show it to you* - probably based on your own computer's (or the database server's) locale settings.

Comment: @MrLister - s'ok - happens all the time :)

Comment: my bad, the startdate is like this in the sqslquery: STARTDATE = CONVERT(nvarchar,GETDATE (),105)

Comment: @user3114347 - then dont do that! Make it `STARTDATE = GetDate()` - dont convert a datetime to a string

Comment: i should change it but i dont have the permission to make changes to the query. The output in the STARTDATE column is now like : 16-10-2015. Suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: Yes, you're trying to parse it as `dd/mm/yyyy` - but its not in that format. Parse it as `dd-mm-yyyy` and it'll work.

Comment: Wait a minute. if the STARTDATE field in the SQL is GetDate(), it is the _current date and time_! So if you can't change the SQL query, why don't you just forget about the STARTDATE field altogether and just use `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `reader` is an SqlDataReader and `"STARTDATE"` is the name of a (nullable) DateTime field in the database, `reader["STARTDATE"]` is already a DateTime object.

That means you can replace the code in the question

```
DateTime.ParseExact(reader["STARTDATE"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null)
```

by a simple

```
(DateTime?)reader["STARTDATE"]
```

Edit:

Based on more comments, the problem is finally becoming clear now: the STARTDATE field from the SQL query is not a DateTime, but is defined as `CONVERT(nvarchar,GETDATE (),105)`

So, since the SQL query can't be changed, the solution is

- either use

  ```
  DateTime.ParseExact(reader["STARTDATE"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", null)
  ```

  since SQL's CONVERT format `105` is defined as returning `dd-MM-yyyy` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)).
- Or, as SQL `GetDate()` is the current date and time anyway, simply discard this result and use

  ```
  DateTime.Now.Date
  ```

  instead.

Answer (score 0):

i should have convert it to the right format: "dd-MM-yyyy"